# Doxygen: Found unknown command `\mathbb'

Tags: latex, doxygen

I used the `mathbb` command in one of the documentation comments

```
/**
 * @brief Represents a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$
 */
```

Added `amsfonts` to `EXTRA_PACKAGES` in my Doxyfile

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = amsfonts
```

Still, I get a warning:

```
warning: Found unknown command `\mathbb'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your brief description is wrong. It probably should read: ...\f$ \mathbb{R}^2 \f$

Comment: Indeed, it is. Thanks! Why doesn't simple `$` work in doxygen? the manual mentions nothing: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/formulas.html

Comment: The $ is see by doxygen as a normal character (in this context) and after this \mathbb is seen as a possible but non existing doxygen command.